# Как считать ввод с клавиатуры без прерываний?

Tags: c, ассемблер, nasm, прерывания

Первичный загрузчик x86

```
global start
extern long_mode_start

section .text
bits 32

start:
    mov esp, stack_top

    call check_multiboot
    call check_cpuid
    call check_long_mode

    call setup_page_tables
    call enable_paging

    lgdt [gdt64.pointer]
    jmp gdt64.code_segment:long_mode_start

    hlt     ;halt OS
check_multiboot:
    cmp eax, 0x36d76289
    jne .no_multiboot
    ret
.no_multiboot:
    mov al, "M"
    jmp error
check_cpuid:
    pushfd
    pop eax
    mov ecx, eax
    xor eax, 1 << 21
    push eax
    popfd
    pushfd
    pop eax
    push ecx
    popfd
    cmp eax, ecx
    je .no_cpuid
    ret
.no_cpuid:
    mov al, "C"
    jmp error
check_long_mode:
    mov eax, 0x80000000
    cpuid
    cmp eax, 0x80000001
    jb .no_long_mode
    
    mov eax, 0x80000001
    cpuid
    test edx, 1 << 29
    jz .no_long_mode
    
    ret
.no_long_mode:
    mov al, "L"
    jmp error
    
setup_page_tables:
    mov eax, page_table_l3
    or eax, 0b11        ;present, writable
    mov [page_table_l4], eax
    mov eax, page_table_l2
    or eax, 0b11        ;present, writable
    mov [page_table_l3], eax
    
    mov ecx, 0      ;counter
.loop:
    mov eax, 0x200000   ;2MiB
    mul ecx
    or eax, 0b10000011 ;present, writable, huge page
    mov [page_table_l2 + ecx * 8], eax
    inc ecx         ; increment counter
    cmp ecx, 512
    jne .loop
    ret
enable_paging:
    ; pass page table location to cpu
    mov eax, page_table_l4
    mov cr3, eax

    ; enable PAE
    mov eax, cr4
    or eax, 1 << 5
    mov cr4, eax

    ; enable long mode
    mov ecx, 0xC0000080
    rdmsr
    or eax, 1 << 8
    wrmsr

    ; enable paging
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 1 << 31
    mov cr0, eax

    ret
    
error:
    mov dword [0xb8000], 0x4f524f45
    mov dword [0xb8004], 0x4f3a4f52
    mov dword [0xb8008], 0x4f204f20 
    mov byte  [0xb800a], al 
    hlt
    
section .bss
align 4096
page_table_l4:
    resb 4096
page_table_l3:
    resb 4096
page_table_l2:
    resb 4096
stack_bottom:
    resb 4096 * 4
stack_top:

section .rodata
gdt64:
    dq 0        ;zero entry
.code_segment: equ $ - gdt64
    dq (1 << 43) | (1 << 44) | (1 << 47) | (1 << 53) ;code segment
.pointer:
    dw $ - gdt64 - 1 ;length
    dq gdt64 ; address
```

Загрузчик х64

```
global long_mode_start

extern kmain

section .text
bits 64

long_mode_start:
    ;set to null
    mov ax, 0
    mov ss, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    call kmain
```

Ядро ОС

```
void kmain(void){
    // Welcome message
    char *welcomeText = strcat("Welcome to TestOS ");
    clear();
    printf(welcomeText);
    newline();
    mulchar_printf('#', strlen(welcomeText));

    //здесь обработать ввод
    ...
}
```

Есть ли возможность прочитать ввод с клавиатуру без использования прерывания 16h и передать введенный символ в Си ядро?

Comment: Клавиатура https://www.frolov-lib.ru/books/bsp/v02/ch2_2.htm  А зачем у Вас обнудение всех сегментных регистров?

Comment: На самом деле обнуление регистров увидел в туториале, ассемблер понимаю не так хорошо и по незнанию оставил

Comment: Кроме прерываний `int-15/16h` и портов `60-61h` есть ещё расположенный в BDA (BiosDataArea) буфер клавиатуры, с которого можно просто забирать введённые символы.